# "undefined" uri segment codeigniter; first function looks for null segment of uri then attempts to use another function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, uri

This is a web app that works when user searches for an item to add to their list and the search results show an item that has previously been added to their list.

However, if the search results find an item that has not previously been added to the user's list then the user should be able to add this new item to their list.

Here's the the first function which works for adding an item that was previously on a user's list;  (note the "if ($user_item_id == 'null' ..." line... this should be calling a second function called "addToUserItems")

```
function addItem() {
    $user_item_id = $this->uri->segment( 3 );
    $master_item_id = $this->uri->segment( 4 );
    $store = $this->uri->segment( 5, '' );
    $user_id = $this->main_model->getMasterUser( $this->user_id );

    if ( $user_item_id == 'null' ) $user_item_id = $this->main_model->addToUserItems( $master_item_id, $user_id );
    $quantity = $this->main_model->addToShoppingList( $user_item_id, $store, $user_id );

    $message  = ( $quantity == '1' ) ? 'Added to list.' : 'On shopping list ' . $quantity . ' times.';
    $message .= '&nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="undo_button" params="unadd/' . $user_item_id . '">Undo?</span>';

    $return = array(
        'message'      => $message,
        'user_item_id' => $user_item_id,
        );
    echo json_encode( $return );
    }
```

Here's the second function which should be setting "user_item_id" but apparently is not;

```
function addToUserItems( $master_item_id, $user_id ) {
    $query = $this->db->query( "
        INSERT INTO user_item ( master_item_id, user_id, custom_category, custom_name, custom_store, expires_after, on_hand )
        SELECT id, " . $user_id . ", original_category, original_name, '', default_expiration, 0
        FROM master_item
        WHERE id = '" . $master_item_id . "'
        ;" );
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Any ideas why we are seeing "user_item_id" undefined?  My guess, after hours of testing assumptions, is that somehow the second function is not setting the value for $user_item_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the suggested fixes; turns out that the user_item_id variable was not being set if the user_item_id field did not have a value. code in other file corrected to include $result['user_item_id'] = 'null'; furthermore, the addItem function above was looking for a user_item_id variable value of 'null' whereas a javascript file, not mentioned in my original question, was looking for the user_item_id variable to be null. so, we had a variable that needed to be set and code in other files which needed to look consistently for 'null' vs null.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9481 & http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27033

Try splitting up the query if you can afford to.. Select the data based on `master_item_id`, then take that and in a separate `insert` query, insert it into `user_item` table. Finally, run `last_insert_id()`.

```
$masterItem = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM master_item WHERE master_item_id = $master_item_id');
$userItem = array();//add master item and user_id stuff
$this->db->insert('user_item',$userItem);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: thanks, the insert into ... select statements are working fine in other areas of the application so I think something else must be going on... the returned URI segment I get when clicking an application button is ... main/addItem/undefined/"master_item_id".  The master_item_id value is correct, it is just that URI segment three should value a numeric value for the id of the newly added entry to the user_item table.  Instead is says "undefined"...

Comment: OK, to start eliminating variables, try just returning `1` from `addToUserItems()` and see if the url is `main/addItem/1/"master_item_id"`. If so, there is a problem with the query...`$this->db->last_query()` will tell you what the query was... you can return that from the addToUserItems and print it out.

Comment: thanks stormdrain... am struggling a bit with some php skills; can you clarify whay you mean by "add master item and user_id stuff"? I have not worked with arrays too much.

Comment: Instead of `return $this->db->insert_id();` try `return 1;` and see what the url is. If the url is `main/addItem/1/...` then we'll know the query isn't running correctly.

Comment: thanks for the suggested fixes; turns out that the user_item_id variable was not being set if the user_item_id field did not have a value. code in other file corrected to include $result['user_item_id'] = 'null';
furthermore, the addItem function above was looking for a user_item_id variable value of 'null' whereas a javascript file, not mentioned in my original question, was looking for the user_item_id variable to be null. so, we had a variable that needed to be set and code in other files which needed to look consistently for 'null' vs null.